# Create an object of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, if-statement

(Using Java) I am implementing a generic class which is a B-Tree. When the user runs the program they can supply some arguments which will determine the type of the tree (Integer, Character, Double or String).

In my main method I have this code:

```
// Get user input and split it into tokens
// Tokens[1] = the type specified by the user

if( tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE"))
    BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();

else if( tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER"))
    BTree<Character> t = new BTree<Character>();

else if( tokens[1].equals("INTEGER"))
    BTree<Integer> t = new BTree<Integer>();

else if( tokens[1].equals("STRING"))
    BTree<String> t = new BTree<String>();
```

But the compiler complains if I have the if statements. If I remove them then it compiles and runs fine :/ how can I fix this? So that the user can supply the type and the tree will be created depending on the type supplied? Thanks.

Here is some of the compiler output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>javac *.java
Main.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();
symbol:   variable BTree
location: class Main

Main.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();
symbol:   variable Double
location: class Main

Main.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();
symbol:   variable t
location: class Main
```

.. There is more but it is similar and repeated for each of the types

Comment: Could you provide compiler log?

Comment: i have edited it into the question :)

Comment: Question title says: `Create an object of an abstract class` but actually you're asking something different.

Comment: Your question states an `abstract` class, or is it simply a `generic` class?

Comment: sorry i meant to say generic.. i edited the question :)

Comment: Looking at your comments below I believe you meant just `generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `t` in each of the `if` statements is only defined in the `if`'s context, outside them the compiler won't recognize them.
Define your variable `t` before the `if` statements.

```
BTree<?> t = null;
if( tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE")) {
    t = new BTree<Double>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER")) {
    t = new BTree<Character>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("INTEGER")) {
    t = new BTree<Integer>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("STRING")) {
    t = new BTree<String>();
}
// now you can use your 't'
```

Comment: @Tim you should also make a habit of inserting brackets for each `if` statement, even for one-liners

Answer (score 1):

Your `BTree<T>` class should not be abstract, since you seem to want to instanciate the same functionality for all kinds of the type `T`.

If you need specific functionality for different types of `T`, you'd need to either implement

```
class CharacterBTree extends BTree<Character>
```

or do it on the fly like

```
 BTree<Character> t = new BTree<Character>() {
    ...
 };
```

Also; declare your `BTree<T> t` variable outside of the if's, so your code becomes

```
BTree<?> t = null;
if ("char".equals(whatever)) {
   t = new BTree<Character>();
} else if {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert curly brackets:

```
if( tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE")){
    BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER")){
    BTree<Character> t = new BTree<Character>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("INTEGER")){
    BTree<Integer> t = new BTree<Integer>();
}
else if( tokens[1].equals("STRING")){
    BTree<String> t = new BTree<String>();
}
```

Or declare your tree before the statetment:

```
BTree<? extends Object> t = null;
if( tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE"))
    t = new BTree<Double>();
else if( tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER"))
    t = new BTree<Character>();
else if( tokens[1].equals("INTEGER"))
    t = new BTree<Integer>();
else if( tokens[1].equals("STRING"))
    t = new BTree<String>();
```

Comment: This'll get it to compile, but using `t` later in a shared way will be difficult.  The fundamental problem is that each `t` is a different type.

Comment: Unless you are only creating the object for the constructor's side effects, this won't help since each `t` is visible only within a one-line scope and not accessible to outside code. Otherwise, you should declare T before the conditional statements and only assign it values within the nested blocks.

Comment: @JeffFoster each `t` is not a different type, they all are the same type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use a case-switch statement (maybe it's not the solution you need, as mishandoff said, seeing the log could help a little bit more) just from a logical point of view:

```
switch(tokens[1]) {
    case "DOUBLE" : BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>(); break;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to something like

```
if (tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE"))
  BTree<Double> t = new BTree<Double>();
else if (tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER"))
  BTree<Character> t = new BTree<Character>();
// etc.

t.doStuff();
```

That won't work.  First, because the `t` variables are only in scope within their `if` statements, and second, because you can't make a variable have different static types along different code paths.

You could do something like

```
BTree<?> t;
if (tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE"))
  t = new BTree<Double>();
else if (tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER"))
  t = new BTree<Character>();
// etc.
```

But then you can't do anything useful with the items stored in `t` afterward because the code that follows doesn't know what it's a tree of.  This is more of a fundamental design problem, not a syntax problem.

You could create an interface — let's call it `ValueHolder` — and use it to define whatever operations you need to do on the values in the tree.  Then define classes like `DoubleHolder`, `CharacterHolder`, and so on, which implement the `ValueHolder` interface.  Then you can write:

```
BTree<? extends ValueHolder> t;
if (tokens[1].equals("DOUBLE"))
  t = new BTree<DoubleHolder>();
else if (tokens[1].equals("CHARACTER"))
  t = new BTree<CharacterHolder>();
// etc.
```

and afterward, you can retrieve items from the tree and they'll be of type `ValueHolder` so you can call any of the methods provided by that interface.